# AWS 503 Service Unavailable on first call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I am running into an issue where my first call to an ECS service I get a 503 service unavailable, but the call after that works successfully. Seems like this issue repeats after a certain time (I have not determined the time window for the issue to repeat yet).

The service is deployed through cloud formation, setting the listener rule in the service.yml file. The priority doesnt clash with any other services in the ECS cluster. The target group inside the yaml file looks fine.

The registered targets inside of the target group are pointing to the correct IP addresses of the tasks in ECS. I verified that information.

Im not sure how to debug this and curious if anyone has ran into something similar. Everything looks like it is properly set up in AWS, I followed it from the Load Balancer to the task in the service.